# How do I modify csv data after upload in vue?

Tags: csv, vue.js, d3.js

This is my CSV data:

```
country,population
China,2535
India,1654
United States,700
Indonesia,680
Brazil,1785
Total,1821
```

this is my code in vue component:

```
import {csv} from 'd3';

//..
data: () => ({
        dataset: [],
    }),
mounted() {
        this.dataLoad()
    },
methods: {
        async dataLoad() {
            let datos = await csv('/datasets/data.csv')
            this.dataset = Object.freeze(datos)
            console.log(this.dataset)
        },
```

and this is console:

[image]

How can I transform population column(string) to numbers for use in my d3 chart?
I have tried this but didn't work

```
csv('/datasets/data.csv').then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.population = +d.population;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
data: () => ({
        dataset: [],
    }),
    async mounted() {
        let datos = await csv('/datasets/data.csv')
        this.dataset = Object.freeze(datos)
        this.dataNumero()
    },
    methods: {
        dataNumero() {
            this.dataset.forEach(d => {d.population = +d.population})
        },
```